# Как правильно сконфигурировать алиасы в BASH для non-login шелла?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

У меня есть файл `.bashrc` вида:

```
alias alias_test='/bin/echo hello word'echo "Check"
```

Когда я логинюсь в шелле мне выводится сообщение "Check", алиас `alias_test` работает. Однако если сделать так:

```
$ ssh 127.0.0.1 alias_test
```

То я получаю:

```
Checkbash: alias_test: command not found
```

Так как сообщение Check было выведено можно быть уверенным, что файл `.bashrc` был выполнен, однако я не понимаю почему алиас не определен.

Скажите, пож., в чем причина и как сделать что бы данный пример работал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man pages of bash:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt

Делайте bash интерактивным, т.е:

> ssh user@host "bash -ic alias_test"

Comment: Спасибо. Я вышел из полодения указав в файле .bashrc код вида:shopt -s expand_aliases

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, поможет создание `~/.bash_profile` со следующим содержанием:

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```